# how to get date by calculated from a specific date with rank of months in excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to get the **End Date** value from **start Date** for next period of months value as below list.

```
Start Date   Months End Date
12-Sep-2016  36 M   ?
16-Mar-2016  30 M   ?
17-Mar-2016  36 M   ?
17-Aug-2015  36 M   ?
14-Jul-2016  36 M   ?
20-Jul-2016  36 M   ?
26-Aug-2015  36 M   ?
20-Aug-2015  30 M   ?
03-Sep-2015  36 M   ?
11-Sep-2015  36 M   ?
06-Apr-2016  36 M   ?
04-Mar-2016  36 M   ?
11-Sep-2015  36 M   ?
26-Feb-2016  36 M   ?
03-Sep-2015  36 M   ?
07-Jun-2016  36 M   ?
25-May-2016  36 M   ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this to **`C2`** and drag it below.

```
=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+B2,DAY(A2))
```

If that "M" letter is text (*not a custom format*) then you can use `Left` formula for `B column`.

```
=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+LEFT(G3,2),DAY(A2))
```

And of course your `C Column` should be in **`Date Format`**

For *specifically months* for *before* or *after* any date, `=EDATE` will also give the expected result:

```
=EDATE(A2,LEFT(G3,2))
```

Comment: What is differece between Edate?

Comment: I gave that example to show the capacity of `=Date` formula. While `=Edate` is only able to show the number of months before or after the date, by the help of `=Date` formula, you can play with either *Day or Month or Year*